# How does Prism WPF Ioc Resolve MainWindow

Tags: prism

```
    protected override Window CreateShell()
    {
        return Container.Resolve<MainWindow>();
    }
```

referring to the above code in Prism/blob/master/Sandbox/Wpf/HelloWorld/HelloWorld/App.xaml.cs,  I do not understand how the MainWindow type is registered with the container.

looking at the registrations of the container, MainWindow type is not listed. 
[image]

Can someone please help me to understand how it works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I do not understand how the MainWindow type is registered with the container

It is not registered with the container. Unity by default resolves concrete types transiently. You only *have* to register a concrete type if you want it to have a non-standard lifetime, e.g. a singleton.

Comment: why is type MainWindow visible to Unity container?  It uses Reflection?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by _visible_, but calling a method with a type parameter for sure _makes the type known to the method_. Internally, Unity uses reflection, not only `Activator.CreateInstance`, but also looking for attributes and so on. Note that this is no different from types that _are_ registered (unless you pass a factory method with the registration, in which case there's no need for `Activator.CreateInstance`).